# Networkx Node Colors in Bokeh/Holoviews Network Diagrams

Tags: python, bokeh, networkx, holoviews

I'm building a network diagram using Networkx and want to consequently plot in holoviews and bokeh.  There seem to be multiple means of annotating and modifying the network nodes (glyph circles), but using the holoviews instantiation of the graph I cannot figure out how to pass the node attribute data to the renderer to color the nodes based on a particular attribute.

It works when I use bokeh only, but plotting the networkx graph object in holoviews doesn't allow me to pass any type of information for coloring the nodes other than a single color.

```
N = hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout,k=1)
                          .opts(tools=['hover','tap'],
                                node_size=20,node_color=G.node[i]['color'])


N.relabel('USCG Structural Condition Network')
N.opts(inspection_policy='edges',bgcolor='lightblue',
       show_legend=True,node_hover_fill_color='red')
```

I thought this would look at a node attribute 'color' and use that as the basis for the node fill color, but I get a random color, e.g. firebrick or purple, instead.

Answer (score 1):

`cmap` option is missing. `node_color` parameter takes the whatever `vdim` you defined in networkx graph.

For example,

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
node_type = np.array(['type1']*17 + ['type2']*17).reshape(34)

for i, _ in enumerate(G.nodes()):
    G.nodes[i]['type'] = node_type[i]
```

```
N = hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout,k=1).opts(tools=['hover','tap'],
                                                                          node_size=10,
                                                                          node_color='type',
                                                                          cmap = ['blue','orange'] 

                                                                         )
```

gives

[colored nodes graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwb1A.png)